# how to store session in single field of mysql seperated by commas?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I want to store session of user in single field of mysql right now I'm doing in this way but its not working how can I do so?
And secondly how can I retrieve that single field to check if user exsits in it or not?

```
    <?php session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['uid']))
    ?>
    <body>
    <?php $uid=$_SESSION['uid'];
      $values[] = $uid;
      $whyus = implode(",",$values);
      $whereclase= " where mainentry.id=".$_GET['id'];  
      $sql = "INSERT INTO mainentry (viewed_list) VALUES ('$whyus')"."$whereclase"; 
      mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure why you want to do this. But the best way, would be using serialization. This can be archived with the PHP function serialize and unserialize or alternatively with json_encode and json_decode.

What you want to do here, is transforming Data into a String. This can be an Object or an Array. Now you can save the String to MySQL. If you want the Value back in some Function, you unserialize or decode the JSON to get your previous Object back.

As far as I know, the json functions may not work with Objects. But im not quite sure in that.

Comment: I want to use it to check if that user has already checked the news then views should not be added and if that user is not in that string than views should be added what do u recomment me for this? what technique should i use to implement this?